# flutter: ScrollBar not always showing

Tags: flutter, gridview, scrollbar

The `scrollBar` in my Flutter app does not always show in my `GridViewBuilder`. It only shows when I begin to scroll.

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

Scrollbar( controller: scrollController,
                                    thumbVisibility: true,
                                    trackVisibility: true,
                                    thickness: 10,
                                    interactive: true,
                                    child: GridView.builder(
                                      controller: scrollController,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      gridDelegate:
                                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                                              mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                                              childAspectRatio: 1
                                              // mainAxisExtent: 50
                                              ),
                                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                                      itemBuilder:
                                          (BuildContext context, int index) { //the rest of logic
}
```

PS: I'm streaming from StreamBuilder

Comment: I just ran your code, it works for me. Maybe the widgets you try to display are not longer than the width of your screen, so no Scrollbar will be shown.

Comment: Does it show immediately you naviagte to that screen? Mine doesn't. I only have to scroll before it shows and always stays showing. But apart from that, when I navigate to that screen without scrolling, it doesn't show

Comment: Navigation shouldn't affect how a widget is displayed. The code above works, you need to search for the issue elsewhere.